# Bounds on the norm $|J'|$, where $J$ is a Jacobi field

Tags: differential-geometry, taylor-expansion, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand the well known formula for the norm of Jacobi fields $J$ along a geodesic $\gamma(t)$  with $J(0)=0$, i.e.
$$
J''(t)+ R(J,\gamma'),\gamma'=0.
$$
The formula
$$
 (\ast) \quad g(J(t),J(t)) = O(t^2)
$$
holds on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ (see e.g. [here](https://witheredstumps.wordpress.com/2020/05/06/jacobi-fields-part-ii/)). In this link the Jacobi equations are used to compute the first two derivatives in $t=0$ and then use a Taylor expansion to argue that the remainder is of higher order. But what I do not understand in this proof is how to make sense of the remainder because it involves $J(t)$ again:
$$
(g(J(t),J(t)))''= 2(g(J''(t),J(t))+ g(J'(t),J'(t)).
$$
So a Taylor expansion yields for some $s_t \in [0,t]$
$$
g(J(t),J(t))= 0+ t\cdot 0 + t^2 \cdot   (g( R(J,\gamma'(s_t)),\gamma'(s_t),J(s_t)))+ g(J'(s_t),J'(s_t)).
$$
How do we estimate the term $g(J'(s_t),J'(s_t))$? For example, how do rule out that
$$
g(J'(s_t),J'(s_t)) \geq \frac{1}{t}? 
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the following trick for second order ODE: Let $f(t) = |J(t)|^2 + |J'(t)|^2$. Then

\begin{align*}
f' &= 2g(J, J') + 2 g(J' , J'') \\
&= 2g(J, J') + 2 g(J' , R(J, \gamma')\gamma')) \\
&\le 2|J| |J'| + 2C |J| |J'| \\
&\le (C+1)( |J|^2 + |J'|^2) = (C+1)f. 
\end{align*}

Here $C$ is the bound on $|R|$. Thus we have the estimates

$$ f(t) \le f(0) e^{(C+1)t}$$

and this implies

$$ |J'(t) |^2 \le f(t) \le f(0) e^{(C+1)t} =  |J'(0)|^2 e^{(C+1)t}$$
since $|J(0)| = 0$.

Comment: I can't understand the inequality in the fourth row. What is the relation between $<J', R(J, \gamma') \gamma'>$ and $C|J||J'|$ ?

Comment: That's the $\langle V, W\rangle \le |V||W|$ for any two vectors $V, W$ and $C$ is the bounds on $R$. @SiyuanYin